# Best way to store Enum value in ActiveRecord and convert to string for display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to store an enum value in activerecord but convert it to a 'title' for display in an app.

I.E.

Review Enum:

```
UNREVIEWED = {:title => "Unreviewed", :name => "UNREVIEWED"}
REVIEWED = {:title => "Reviewed", :name => "REVIEWED"}
FLAGGED = {:title => "Flagged as inappropriate", :name => "FLAGGED"}
```

So in java land I was used to storing the ENUMs name ie (REVIEWED) in the database and then converting that name into that actual enum on the server such that I could call helper methods on it, ie:

```
review = Review.valueOf(review)
review.title()
```

Is there something similar I can do in rails to accomplish this?

FYI we are trying to keep our app super small so if I can easily accomplish this or something similar without a GEM that would be great.

Any 'standard' way to do this, as I imagine I am not the first to struggle with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally when using an enum you are storing an int value in the database and converting in a string in your application.

Answer (score 29):

ActiveRecord enums is the best way to go since it's a part of the framework (since version 4.1).

Its usage is quite simple:

**Migration**:

```
class AddEnumToMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :my_model, :status, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

**Model:**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:draft, :beta, :public]
end
```

Then use it a will:

```
MyModel.draft # gets all drafts
MyModel.last.draft? # checks if the last model is draft
MyModel.last.status # gets the string description of the status of my model
```

For mode information refer to [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: ActiveRecord enums store values as integers, right? That's inherently unsafe in a project with migrations since you may remove an enum value later and renumber all successive ones.Here's a girst of a simple Enum class that  saves values as strings. https://gist.github.com/alexch/a7be54e1b085718473ff

Comment: See this article for more gotchas with the int-to-string Rails enum: https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/

Comment: @AlexChaffee per the API docs, "it’s also possible to explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer with a Hash", e.g. `enum status: { draft: 0, beta: 1, public: 2 }`, which removes the danger of adding/removing/re-ordering later

Answer (score 6):

there are a lot of posts about this issue, i guess that this points to most of them: http://thinkinginrails.com/2010/04/using-enums-for-constants/

i think that this is an over engineered thing, that you don't need in a dynamically typed language like ruby.

just use strings!

you could then use that like:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => ["UNREVIEWED", "REVIEWED", "FLAGGED"]
  def status
    read_attribute(:status)
  end
  def status= (value)
    write_attribute(:status, value)
  end
end
```

Comment: I am definitely green when it come to Ruby and Rails.  Does you solution provide a to translate from the string stored to a string that I would want to present to the user?  your two status methods are confusing me.  Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: i copied the solution from an example that uses symbols instead of strings. those two methods then did the from-symbol-to-symbol conversion. it's not needed here, but it shows how you could even map it to some integer or whatever database representation you like.

Comment: the conversion to a user-readable form should be handled by I18n as a best practice. you can then lookup those keys using the ```t``` aka ```I18n.tranlsate``` method like ```t("status.#{review.status}")```

Comment: i18n translate for a simple enum constant to string translation?  Now that seems like over engineering;  All I want to do is convert a constant ('enum') to human readable string.

Comment: KISS is king! if you don't need it, you can also use rails methods like ```humanize``` etc. i am working on apps in german, so i need to use ```I18n``` anyhow.

Comment: I see your point about overengineering, but your code example only provides a fraction of the functionality that `enum` would provide. If you rewrote your example to use `enum` you'd also get instance methods like `flagged?` (is this review flagged?) and `flagged!` (update this review's status to 'flagged' and save) for each possible status, plus class-level scopes like `Review.flagged` (return all flagged reviews) - all with a single line of code

Comment: this was pre `enum` rails features

Answer (score 5):

Using @Godsaur example.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:draft, :beta, :public]
end
```

You can get the string value as:

```
MyModel.last.status
=> "beta"
```

But if you want a "title" you can:

```
MyModel.last.status.titleize
=> "Beta"
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that @Godsaur answer is correct - I personally don't like the approach of storing integer values to represent meaningful string equivalents (provided that enough database indexing is made and/or the cost of querying strings in the DB engine is similar to that of querying integers).

My approach is usually storing the text values in the database (for easier understanding of DB records).

#### my_model.rb

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATUSES = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({unverified: 'unverified', reviewed: 'reviewed', flagged: 'flagged'})
  #the text values are similar to their symbols key
  #you could also define additional attributes for each key if needed. Ex:
  #STATUSES = {unverified: {title: 'Unverified Text Title', txt: 'unverified'}, ...}

  # assuming a 'status' field
  scope :unverified, -> { where(status: STATUSES[:unverified]) }

  def unverified?
    status == STATUSES[:unverified]
  end

  # Or
  STATUSES.each do |sym, val|
    define_method("#{sym}?") {status == val}
  end
end
```

#### my_view.erb

```
<%= MyModel::STATUSES[@my_model.status] %> or 
<%= MyModel::STATUSES[@my_model.status].title %>
```

Comment: -1 Using strings for this type of data is a bad practice, and your reason for doing so is terrible.  Why are you spending so much time in the raw database, rather than accessing the data through the application?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tamersalama. Here's a simple way to do it using strings in the DB with a custom Enum class. Note that this also supports human readable names for use in dropdown menus.

https://gist.github.com/alexch/a7be54e1b085718473ff

SQL:

```
Table name: snacks
 id                         :integer
 ice_cream                  :string
```

Rails:

```
class Snack < ActiveRecord::Base
  FLAVORS = Enum.new [
      [:vanilla, "Vanilla"],
      [:chocolate, "Chocolate"],
      [:rocky_road, "Rocky Road"]
      ])
  ]
end
```

HTML:

```
<%= simple_form_for @snack do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select :ice_cream, Snack::FLAVORS, :value, :label %>
<% end %>
```