# Best practice/most efficient for rails activerecord storage of field with very reduced set of possible values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to create my models for storing users and different contact information fields.
The idea is to allow a user to have 0 or more registered contact info (eg. 2 telephone numbers, 1 Skype account, personal and work email addresses), so I understand I cannot add said fields to the users model, nor is a good idea in my case to model phone, skype, email, etc as individual tables. This makes me consider using a generic contact info table, with a column for the type of contact info (eg. phone, im, email) and the contact info itself.
My doubt, due to my lack of experience on this matter, is this: Should I use an integer for the contact info type and handle it on the controller/view side (either through an array or case-like fashion)? Or would it be better to just use a string (gaining clarity in the db data, but with the added penalty in storage, validation and normalization times of said strings)? Is there any best practice regarding this?

I tried searching in multiple ways, but after reading or skimming through 20+ articles I couldn't find anything even close to what I'm trying to ask.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store Enum value in ActiveRecord and convert to string for display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911977/best-way-to-store-enum-value-in-activerecord-and-convert-to-string-for-display)

Comment: The storage difference between an integer and a short string really isn't worth worrying about anymore. If you have a sensible database then you could add a CHECK constraint to take care of the validation (and note that this validation really does belong in the database anyway, even if you used numbers). A string also lets you look directly at your database (i.e. without Rails or anything else in the way) and get easily interpreted results without having to remember what a bunch of numbers mean.

Answer (score 0):

there's rails' built in [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), which you can use in such a case. it maps integer to string values. e.g.

```
class Contact < Activerecord::Base
  enum contact_type: {email: 0, phone: 1}
  #enum contact_type: [:email, :phone]
end
```

i would not use it without explicitly stating the name to integer mapping. if somebody changed the order of values in the array at some later point, the meaning of the contact_type would suddenly change all over your application, because the already stored integers in the database wouldn't automagically change as well.